# Magento 2 getIncludeInMenu returns Null

Tags: magento2, category, magento-2.1, menu, magento2.1.0

I need to make sure only menu items i.e. categories with the flag **Include in Menu** set to true to be shown in the main  menu.

As far as I understood, using `$category->getIncludeInMenu()` should do the magic by returning the value. My calls always return **Null**.

Now I thought: if I can call the method `getIncludeInMenu()` it should return the right value. Otherwise this method is useless ;-/

Code extracts:
**Menu.php**

```
protected function getActiveChildren($parent, $level)
{
    $activeChildren = array();
    // --- check level ---
    $maxLevel = $this->getConfig('is_level');
    if(!$maxLevel) $maxLevel = 3;
    if ($maxLevel > 0)
    {
        if ($level >= ($maxLevel - 1)) return $activeChildren;
    }
    $childs = $parent->getChildrenCategories();
    if (count($childs))
    {
        foreach ($childs as $child) 
        {
            if ($child->getIsActive())
            {
                array_push($activeChildren, $child);
            }
        }
    }
    return $activeChildren;
}
```

When I change
`if ($child->getIsActive())`
to
`if ($child->getIsActive() && $child->getIncludeInMenu())` all categories are hidden because `getIncludeInMenu()` return **Null** all the time...

Any hint appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The problem

The call to `getIncludeInMenu` returns NULL because the value is not part of the collection.

Basically, you get your child categories by calling `getChildrenCategories`. The details of that method can be found in `Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category.php` :

```
public function getChildrenCategories($category)
{
    $collection = $category->getCollection();
    /* @var $collection \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection */
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect(
        'url_key'
    )->addAttributeToSelect(
        'name'
    )->addAttributeToSelect(
        'all_children'
    )->addAttributeToSelect(
        'is_anchor'
    )->addAttributeToFilter(
        'is_active',
        1
    )->addIdFilter(
        $category->getChildren()
    )->setOrder(
        'position',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Select::SQL_ASC
    )->joinUrlRewrite()->load();

    return $collection;
}
```

As you can see the `include_in_menu` attribute is not added to select, thus every category from that collection don't have this attribute that's why the `getIncludeInMenu` call always returns NULL.

### Possible fix

My suggestion to fix that would be to replace the following code:

```
$childs = $parent->getChildrenCategories();
```

With:

```
$childs = $parent->getChildrenCategories();
// Clear the collection
$childs->clear();
// Add the missing attribute to be selected in the collection
$childs->addAttributeToSelect('include_in_menu');
// Reload the collection
$childs->load();
```